# Deploying Linq-to-SQL C# application that contains service based database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I built a C# application in Visual Studio with Linq-to-SQL and it contains a service-based database (`.mdf` file). I want to deploy it to another computer so it can be used there.

I have already created the setup installer using Visual Studio installer -> Setup project in my solution. I try to install it in another computer. After the installation is completed, I can open the application.

But when I want to access the database I get this error:

> Microsoft .NET Framework: Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> The underlying provider failed on open.

Can anyone help? I'm new to C# programming, I use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express and Visual Studio 2015. Thank you

Here's the error log:

`See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text ************** System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files\Techno zone\LocalACC\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at SmallProject.AllTransactionForm.btnShowAll_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded Assemblies ************** 
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
---------------------------------------- SmallProject
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Techno%20zone/LocalACC/SmallProject.exe
---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
---------------------------------------- System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
---------------------------------------- EntityFramework
    Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.1.40302.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Techno%20zone/LocalACC/EntityFramework.DLL
---------------------------------------- System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
---------------------------------------- EntityFramework.SqlServer
    Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.1.40302.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Techno%20zone/LocalACC/EntityFramework.SqlServer.DLL
---------------------------------------- Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Data.OracleClient
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data.OracleClient/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.OracleClient.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
---------------------------------------- System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
---------------------------------------- System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1532.0 built by: NETFXREL1LAST

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll

************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled with debugging enabled.

For example:

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by this dialog box.`

Comment: Kindly post the error(exception) details so that we may help

Comment: You can't just copy an mdf file to another computer. The other machine should have Sql Server installed as well (at least localdb) and the connection string should be correct.

Comment: I tried it on my PC (has Sql Server installed) and still get this error. I don't copy the mdf file, I create a setup project for my application. But when I create the setup project and installed it on my PC, there is no database file in the folder, only EntityFramework.dll, EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, myproject.exe and myrpoject.exe.config.

Comment: Here's my connection string: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SmallProject\SmallProject\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True

Comment: Installing an application is basically copying files. If you just drop an mdf file in some directory, it won't be accessible just like that.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Have You Tried Deattaching and Then Attaching Database? 
 If Not Then Read Have Look At Solution Briefed Below.** 

If I'm not wrong you are using Sql Server 2012. You just simply need to do is open Sql Server and do right click on your database -> Drop Down Will Appear -> Look For Deattach - Hit That Button. Now You Copy Your .mdf file. Now in second computer / in your client computer follow these steps:-
1) Open Sql Server.
2) Right click on Connection Detail appearing at Top Left Corner in Hierarchy Format, A drop down will appear -> Look for attach database button -> Click -> Now browse for .mdf file which you've deattached from your pc and now its time to attach in second PC. click submit. Now your database will be appearing in Connection Hierarchy. That's It. Now start your application if problem persist please do share with us :) and if problem is solved then click this answer as verified / accepted .. :)  I hope this solution can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

go to your project properties. in publish tab open 'application files' , then find your mdf file and change it's publish status to 'Data File(Auto)'.